# Htaccess rewrite to two different folders depending on path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two folders, `app` and `landing`. The `landing` folder serves a SPA and must be displayed when the users are reaching `/`, `/images/.*` or `/_next/.*`. Every other url path should make an internal rewrite the `app` folder. So I wrote this .htaccess in the folder whith `landing` and `app`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect root, _next and assets paths to landing folder and subsequent resources
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(_next|images|)(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /landing/$1 [L]

# Redirect everything else to app
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
```

When I go to / my browser is redirected to /app/public/landing. But if I remove the last line, the landing shows up correctly.

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, rewriting "loops" until no more rules match. The `%{REQUEST_URI}` value changes with internal rewrites. So after your first rule applied, it goes into a second round with the request URI now being `/landing/...`, and on that your RewriteCond does not apply any more. So the second rule gets executed now. Try and use the `E` flag instead, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end

Answer (score 0):

The `L` flag stops the rewriting process *for the current run* . That means that the rewritten location is *again* rewritten in the next run. Since the location `/landing/...` does not match the first rule's condition the second condition get's applied, the request gets rewritten to `/app/landing/...`

You have two immediate options:

Either use the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag which terminates the rewriting process completely, not just for the current run:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect root, _next and assets paths to landing folder and subsequent resources
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(_next|images)/?
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(/.*)$ /landing$1 [END]

# Redirect everything else to app
RewriteRule ^ /app/%1 [L]
```

Or add a condition to the second rule too:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect root, _next and assets paths to landing folder and subsequent resources
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(_next|images)/?
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(/.*)$ /landing$1 [END]

# Redirect everything else to app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landing/?
RewriteRule ^ /app%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Note: I also fixed some other minor issues with your implementation.